# MS Access SQL: Replacing a field with a string + another row value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a table in MS Access database which contains some movie information

```
    [Table:Movies]
    MovieName         CrewId      CrewMember
    The Big Lebowski        1       Joel Coen
    The Big Lebowski        2       Ethel Coen
    The Big Lebowski        3       Carter Burwell
    The Big Lebowski        4       Roger Deakins
    The Matrix              1       Andy Wachowski
    The Matrix              2       Lana Wachowski
    The Matrix              3       Don Davis
    The Matrix              4       Bill Pope
```

CrewId 1 is director and 2 is co/assistant director, and so on.

What i am trying to do is replace co-director name in 'CrewMember' column with "Assistant of Director Name", like below

```
    [Table:Movies]

    MovieName         CrewId      CrewMember
    The Big Lebowski        1       Joel Coen
    The Big Lebowski        2       Assistant of Joel Coen
    The Big Lebowski        3       Carter Burwell
    The Big Lebowski        4       Roger Deakins
    The Matrix              1       Andy Wachowski
    The Matrix              2       Assistant of Andy Wachowski
    The Matrix              3       Don Davis
    The Matrix              4       Bill Pope
```

I am using the following query which is giving Syntax error (missing operator).

```
    UPDATE t1
    SET t1.CrewMember = 'Assistant of '+ t2.CrewMember
    FROM Movies t1, Movies t2
    WHERE t1.MovieName = t2.MovieName
    AND t1.CrewId = 2
    AND t2.CrewId = 1;
```

Please help me with this query

Comment: After you replace 'ethel cohen' and 'lana wachoswki', do you plan to keep their names around anywhere?

Comment: No. That is to be replaced by the new string. btw Fabians solution worked. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE Movies as t1, Movies as t2
SET t1.CrewMember = 
'Assistant of ' + t2.CrewMember
WHERE t1.MovieName=t2.MovieName AND t1.CrewId=2 AND t2.CrewId=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabian. I still don't know what i was doing wrong but your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: There is no FROM clause in the UPDATE syntax, you need to put both table after the UPDATE  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221186(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In Access, string concatonation is done using "&"

So it should be:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.CrewMember = 'Assistant of '& t2.CrewMember
    FROM Movies t1, Movies t2
    WHERE t1.MovieName = t2.MovieName
    AND t1.CrewId = 2
    AND t2.CrewId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the reason is because the string concatenation operator in Access is `&`, not `+`.  Also, I think Access requires the `as` for table aliases, and you can use a `join` for the condition:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.CrewMember = 'Assistant of '+ t2.CrewMember
    FROM Movies as t1 join
         Movies as t2
         on t1.MovieName = t2.MovieName
    where t1.CrewId = 2 AND t2.CrewId = 1;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried everything you suggested first individually and then at the same time but i'm still getting the same error. 
`
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "Assistant of' & t2.CrewMember 
FROM Movies t1
JOIN Movies as t2
ON t1.MovieName = t2.MovieName'.
`
and it highlights FROM in the query after dismissing error dialog.

Comment: @JSmith, in your error message, it looks like you used both a double and a single quote.  While you can use one or the other, you just can't use them interchangably in the same statement.  Try just one or the other, i.e. `"Assistant of" & `

Comment: i noticed that and re checked my query. I have used single quotes in my query for the string. The opening double quote appears only in the error message. Its strange.